# Calculate $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{ (1^{1^p}2^{2^p}\cdot...\cdot n^{n^p})^{ 1/n^{p+1} }}{n^{1/(p+1)}}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits

> Calculate:
>   $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{ (1^{1^p}2^{2^p}\cdot...\cdot n^{n^p})^{ 1/n^{p+1} }}{n^{1/(p+1)}}$$

I've done some steps as follows: $$a_n:=\frac{ (1^{1^p}2^{2^p}\cdot...\cdot n^{n^p})^{ 1/n^{p+1} }}{n^{1/(p+1)}} \iff \ln a_n=\frac{1}{n^{p+1}}\big(\sum_{k=1}^nk^p\ln k-\frac{n^{p+1}}{p+1}\ln n\big) \iff \\\ln a_n =\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n\big[\big(\frac{k}{n}\big)^p\ln \frac{k}{n}\big]+\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n\big(\frac{k}{n}\big)^p\ln n-\frac{\ln n}{p+1}.$$
Then, I was wondering if I could make some integrals out of it but still there are some odd terms.

I think my approach isn't so good...

Comment: Do you know that $$\sum_{k=1}^{n}k^p=\frac{n^{p+1}}{p+1}+\frac{n^p}{2}+O(n^{p-1})$$ where $p$ is a positive integer?

Comment: Your desired limit of $\log a_n$ is easily seen to be a Riemann integral corresponding to first term.

Comment: You can also get the limit via Cesaro-Stolz.

Comment: Your dots between 2 and $n$ form a smiley like pattern. Better use `\dots`.

Comment: (Yet [another](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2018793) duplicate. Arming myself with a broom...)

Comment: @metamorphy Could you please teach me how to search the site more efficiently? I couldn't find this question before posting myself :(

Comment: @VIVID: I use [approach0.xyz](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Clim_%7Bn%5Cto%5Cinfty%7D%20%5Cfrac%7B%20(1%5E%7B1%5Ep%7D2%5E%7B2%5Ep%7D%5Ccdot%E2%80%A6%5Ccdot%20n%5E%7Bn%5Ep%7D)%5E%7B%201%2Fn%5E%7Bp%2B1%7D%20%7D%7D%7Bn%5E%7B1%2F(p%2B1)%7D%7D%24&p=1) (in addition to the built-in [M]SE searcher).

Comment: @metamorphy Thank you this site seems to be so useful :)

Comment: @ParamanandSingh It seems you have solved this via Cesaro-Stolz. Could you help me understand the linked solution? I don't understand why ln(n) is written instead of ln(n+1) in some places while using Stolz-Cesaro... It would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: You need to learn Cesaro-Stolz Theorem properly : if sequence $b_n$ is monotone and diverges to $\infty $ or $-\infty$ and $(a_{n+1}-a_n)/(b_{n+1}-b_n)$ tends to a limit $L$ (finite or infinite) then so does $a_n/b_n$. You can see how $n+1$ comes into picture here.

Comment: My own answer is available here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1775105/72031 but it does not make use of Cesaro-Stolz.

Answer (score 3):

I seem to remember answering this question sometimes, but I didn't find it! So,  I write the answer again, I didn't COPY my previous answer. Thank @metamorphy for   pointing out this！The following is my previous answer.
[Computing limit of a product](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3205227/computing-limit-of-a-product/3205260#3205260)

$$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n\big[\big(\frac{k}{n}\big)^p\ln \frac{k}{n}\big]
\to\int_{0}^{1}x^p\ln x dx.$$
is not difficult.

What you really need is the limit:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\left(\sum_{k=1}^n\big(\frac{k}{n}\big)^p\ln n-\frac{\ln n}{p+1}\right)
=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)^p-\frac{1}{p+1}\right)\ln n=0.$$

To get this, we have the following result(https://math.stackexchange.com/a/149174/72031):
Suppose $f'$ exists on $[a,b]$, let 
$$A_n=\frac{b-a}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}f\bigg(a+\frac{k(b-a)}{n}\bigg)
 -\int_{a}^{b}f(x)\mathrm{d}x,$$
then
$$\color{red}{\lim_{n\to \infty}nA_n=\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{2}(b-a).}$$

Comment: +1 here. A proof of the result you use is given here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/149174/72031 Alternatively one can use Cesaro-Stolz.

Comment: Yes, it's kind of you, I cann' find the result I use just now!

Comment: I seem to remember answering this question sometimes, but I didn't find it!  As you see , I write the answer again, I didn't COPY my previous answer. Thank you for you pointing out this！@metamorphy

Answer (score 1):

Assuming $p > -1$, continuing your split up series.

1 .This is was WA gives us for the first summation. [First sum, e.g. $p=3$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=limit&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C%20%22Limit%22%2C%20%22limit%22%7D%20-%3E%22infinity%22&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C%20%22Limit%22%2C%20%22limitfunction%22%7D%20-%3E%221%2Fx%20sum_k%3D1%5Ex%20%28k%2Fx%29%5E3log%28k%2Fx%29%22&assumption=%7B%22C%22%2C%20%22limit%22%7D%20-%3E%20%7B%22Calculator%22%7D) $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)^p\ln \frac{k}{n} = -\frac{1}{(p+1)^2}$$. 
EDIT: Using the hint from @Riemann, this sum is equal to $\int_0^1x^p\ln(x)dx=-\frac{1}{(p+1)^2}$, for $p>-1$.

2. Second $$\frac{\ln n}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)^p - \frac{\ln n}{p+1}=\ln n\left[\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)^p-\frac{1}{p+1}\right] = \ln n\left[\frac{1}{n^{p+1}}\sum_{k=1}^nk^p-\frac{1}{p+1}\right].$$
   $\sum_{k=1}^nk^p$ can be written using [Bernoulli numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_number) as $$\sum_{k=1}^nk^p=\frac{n^{p+1}}{p+1}+\frac{1}{2}n^p+\sum_{k=2}^p\frac{B_k}{k!}p^\underline{k-1}n^{p-k+1},$$
   and thus we obtain $$\frac{1}{p+1}+\frac{1}{2}\frac{n^p}{n^{p+1}}+\frac{n^{p+1}}{n^{p+1}}\sum_{k=2}^p\frac{B_k}{k!}p^\underline{k-1}n^{-k}-\frac{1}{p+1}=$$
   $$\frac{1}{2n}+\sum_{k=2}^p\frac{B_k}{k!}p^\underline{k-1}n^{-k}.$$
   And therefore, since $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\ln n}{n} = 0$, $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\ln n}{2n}+\sum_{k=2}^p\frac{B_k}{k!}p^\underline{k-1}\frac{\ln n}{n^{k}}=0$$

Combing the two series,
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\ln a_n = -\frac{1}{(p+1)^2} + 0$$ and (to me somehow surprising)
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=e^{-\frac{1}{(p+1)^2}}$$